# Track down which resource limits index creation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index

This index creation is slow (2 million rows) :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_index_id ON foo (id);
```

I modified several parameters which did not significantly affect total time:

- *max_parallel_maintenance_workers*
- *maintenance_work_mem*

The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createindex.html) states that I/O and CPU can be bottlenecks.

> Increasing max_parallel_maintenance_workers may allow more workers to
> be used, which will reduce the time needed for index creation so long
> as the index build is not already I/O bound. Of course, there should
> also be sufficient CPU capacity that would otherwise lie idle.

How can I check which resource is actually a bottleneck ?

I tried to run an explain plan with I/O timings to guess, but [it is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484346/explain-analyze-on-create-index-with-postgresql) for such queries.

(the database is hosted by a DBaaS, so I have no access to the server itself to get OS metrics)

Answer (score 1):

Use `top` and see if the associated processes take 100% of a CPU core. If yes, you are CPU bound, if not, you should be I/O bound.

Note that building indexes has different stages, which may exhibit different characteristics. You can look at `pg_stat_progress_create_index` to see what it is doing and how far it is.

Comment: Well, I have no access to OS metrics, as stated in the question. 

If I would have them, I would use utilities (eg iotop for IO) on the specific process id I can get from pg_stat_activity.backend_type= 'parallel worker'.

All I have is CPU and memory consumption (no I/O) on the whole database, so I can't figure out which I caused by index build and which is related to other queries.

Comment: I didn't see that. Then you are out of luck. One of the disadvantages of hosted databases: you are at the mercy of what your provider lets you see.